# jQuery onclick add the class en remove it when another item selected

Tags: jquery, css, click

I am wondering what I am doing wrong here.
I have a list which can be selected, and when selected the "clicked" class is set. But when I choose another item, the prev item should be deselected and pass the clicked class to the new item, but in my case this isn't happening!?

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(".select-examn-row-item").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
    }, function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked') ){
            $(this).removeClass('hovered');
        }
    }
);

$(".select-examn-row-item").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.stopPropagation;
    $(this).find('clicked').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

Maybe someone can guide me in this one.
[And my working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justamir/o5r8o6ut/2/)

Comment: @j08691 I just updated my fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your remove class click is missing the . prefix. Also, you're removing clicked from child element then adding it to parent. The logic doesn't work. 
And there are multiple behaviors occuring with the hovered also that needs to be managed.
One soluetion would be replacing your remove class call with this:

```
$('.clicked:not(:hover)').removeClass('clicked hovered');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sfwo6gxn/

Answer (score 2):

**Modifications:**
for hover functionality add a css class instead of script.

```
.select-examn-row-item:hover {
        background-color: #fa6a00;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

add the class `.clicked` which is missing in your css

```
.clicked{  background-color: #fa6a00;
        color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;}
```

and remove class should be `$('.select-examn-row-item').removeClass('clicked');` not from  `$(this).find('clicked').removeClass('clicked');`

```js
$(".select-examn-row-item").click(function(){
   
    $('.select-examn-row-item').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
   
});
```

```css
.select {
    /*width: 300px;*/
    /*border: 1px solid #eee;*/
    color: #444444;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

    .select-examn-row-item {
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        color: #444;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
        position: relative;
        height: 16px;
    }
    .select-examn-row-item:last-child {border: transparent;}
    
    .select-examn-row-item .selectableRow:after {
        content:"";
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border-top:18px solid transparent;
        border-bottom:18px solid transparent;
        border-left:18px solid #fff;
        position: absolute;
        right: -18px;
        top: 0;
    }
    
    .select-examn-row-item:hover {
        background-color: #fa6a00;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
.clicked{  background-color: #fa6a00;
        color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;}
    
    .select-examn-row-item.hovered .selectableRow:after {
        border-left:18px solid #fa6a00;
    }
    
    .select-examn-row-item .selectableRow i.arrow {
        width: 6px;
        height: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        background: url('http://s7.postimg.org/ze62pveef/arrow.png') right top no-repeat;
        background-size: 6px 20px;
    }
        .select-examn-row-item.hovered .selectableRow i.arrow {
            color: #fff;
            background-position: right bottom;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
    <div class="select-examn-row-item">
        <div class="selectableRow">First Item <i class="arrow"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-examn-row-item">
        <div class="selectableRow">Second Item <i class="arrow"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-examn-row-item">
        <div class="selectableRow">Third Item <i class="arrow"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```